# How to await promise function inside nested maps?

Tags: javascript

Suppose I have the following:

```
async function getReactionScores(userReactions) {
  const reactionsWithSharesPromises = userReactions.map((reactions) => {
    return {
      emoji: reactions.emoji,
      shares: reactions.users.map(async (user) => {
        return {
          username: user.username,
          // Just as an example of something to wait for
          shares: await sleep(1, user.id),
        };
      }),
    };
  });

}

function sleep(time, userID) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve(userID), time));
}
```

How do I await for all the promises inside the second map to resolve? If it was only one map, I could do Promise.all, but promise all is not recursive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need 2 Promise.all

```
async function getReactionScores(userReactions) {
  const reactionsWithSharesPromises = await Promise.all(userReactions.map(async (reactions) => {
    return {
      emoji: reactions.emoji,
      shares: await Promise.all(reactions.users.map(async (user) => {
        return {
          username: user.username,
          // Just as an example of something to wait for
          shares: await sleep(1, user.id),
        };
      })),
    };
  }));
}
```

Comment: So if I had N levels of `map` but only a promise in the inner-most one, would I also need to enclose all of them in Promise.all's?

Comment: Long story short: yes. In general effectful computations like promises are "contagious": everything that uses async code becomes async. If you examine your code you will notice that you have this rule broken: `getReactionScores` is async, first iteratee `(reactions) => {` is not, then second iteratee is async again `async (user) => {`. To make it work you need to make first iteratee async as well and wrap with promise.all.